# Can't run JSP files on Tomcat 9 : Unable to set last modified date for file

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I use Eclipse 2020-03(4.15.0), Tomcat v9.0.53 with java 11.0.11 on ubuntu.

When I create a Dynamic Web Project everything works fine. When I try to use a JSP file, I got this error 500 (on every JSP files):

Here I try to access to `http://localhost:8080/TP4/form.jsp`

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/TP4] threw exception [Unable to set last modified date for file [/data/Documents/S3/JEE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/TP4/org/apache/jsp/form_jsp.java]] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to set last modified date for file [/data/Documents/S3/JEE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/TP4/org/apache/jsp/form_jsp.java]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:394)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:367)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:605)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:399)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

And if I spam F5 on the same page I got this error :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/TP4] threw exception [org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.form_jsp] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.form_jsp
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:158)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:192)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I tried to re-install Tomcat, but I still got the error. I also check in the temporary files of the server, and it succeed to update the date of the files.

Do you have any clue about how can I fix this ?

Comment: Check permission on that file.

Comment: It's 770, so that souldn't be a problem, right ?

Comment: 770 allow for access to owner and group. Ultimate access for all is 777. Try it if it helps, then tomcat runs under wrong user, or doesn't have proper group.